# Using tcpdump with iptables?

Tags: iptables, tcpdump

I use iptables to block different kind of attacks on my server. We have a different set of rules along with different rate-limit rules. Now I also use a script that would observe the threshold if it were greater than 10mb/s and dump all the packets to a file. This script keeps running all the time in a screen session and uses the following command to dump:

```
tcpdump -nn -s0 -c 2000 -w Attack.cap
sleep 300
```

Once attacked, it waits 5 minutes to check for another attack (sleep 300). Now I doubt if during the packets capture process, iptables still work because in /var/messages I see lines like "eth0 entered promiscuous mode" and "eth0 left promiscuous mode" so it might over-look iptables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode

> In computer networking, promiscuous mode or promisc mode is a mode for
>   a wired network interface controller (NIC) or wireless network
>   interface controller (WNIC) that causes the controller to pass all
>   traffic it receives to the central processing unit (CPU) rather than
>   passing only the frames that the controller is intended to receive.

This does not bypass any kind of firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the command

```
 tcpdump -i eth0 -p  nn -s0 -c 2000 -w Attack.cap
```

By default `tcpdump` will put the interface into promiscuous mode.  For your purposes, I don't believe you need promiscuous mode for what you are doing.  Specifying the inteface prevents `tcpdump` from looking for it, and possibly getting the wrong interface.

`tcpdump` grabs the raw packets before they get firewalled by `iptables`, so you will be able to see packets that get dropped or rejected by the firewall.

Comment: I'm already seeing packets that get dropped by the Firewall so I don't think "promiscious mode" has anything to do there. The only reason why I asked it was because I doubted the firewall not to work because my server made a response to incoming packet but later I realize that the attack maybe passed the filter rules.

Comment: @AsadMoeen Promiscuous mode can increase the load on your network stack by disabling the Ethernet card's on-board filtering.  This depends on the network traffic and the boards capabilities.